# Why won't my column name change work in R?

Tags: r, rename

This is part of a script im writing to merge the collumns more fully after using `merge()`.
If both datasets have a column with the same name `merge()` gives you columns `column.x` and `column.y`. 
 I have written a script to put this data together and to drop the unneeded columns (which would be `column.y` and `column.x_error`, a column i've added to give warnings in case `dat$column.x != dat$column.y)`. 
I also want to rename `column.x` to `column`, to decrease unneeded manual actions in my dataset. I have not managed to rename `column.x` to `column`, see the code for more info.

`dat` is obtained from doing a `dat = merge(data1,data2, by= "ID", all.x=TRUE)`

```
#obtain a list of double columns
dubbelkol = cbind()
sorted = sort(names(dat))
for(i in as.numeric(1:length(names(dat)))) {
  if(grepl(".x",sorted[i])){
    if (grepl(".y", sorted[i+1]) && (sub(".x","",sorted[i])==sub(".y","",sorted[i+1]))){
      dubbelkol = cbind(dubbelkol,sorted[i],sorted[i+1])
    } 
  }  
}

#Check data, fill in NA in column.x from column.y if poss
temp = cbind()
for (p in as.numeric(1:(length(dubbelkol)-1))){
  if(grepl(".x",dubbelkol[p])){
    dat[dubbelkol[p]][is.na(dat[dubbelkol[p]])] = dat[dubbelkol[p+1]][is.na(dat[dubbelkol[p]])]
    temp = (dat[dubbelkol[p]] != dat[dubbelkol[p+1]])
    colnames(temp) = (paste(dubbelkol[p],"_error", sep=""))
    dat[colnames(temp)] = temp
  }
}
#If every value in "column.x_error" is TRUE or NA, delete "column.y" and "column.x_error"
#Rename "column.x" to "column"
#from here until next comment everything works
droplist= c()
for (k in as.numeric(1:length(names(dat)))) {
  if (grepl(".x_error",colnames(dat[k]))) {
    if (all(dat[k]==FALSE, na.rm = TRUE)) {
      droplist = c(droplist,colnames(dat[k]), sub(".x_error",".y",colnames(dat[k])))
#the next line doesnt work, it's supposed to turn the .x column back to "" before the .y     en .y_error columns are dropped.
      colnames(dat[sub(".x_error",".x",colnames(dat[k]))])= paste(sub(".x_error","",colnames(dat[k])))
    }
  }
}
dat = dat[,!names(dat) %in% droplist]
```

`paste(sub(".x_error","",colnames(dat[k])))` will give me `"BNR"` just fine, but the `colnames(...) = ...` won't change the column name in `dat`.

Any idea what's going wrong?

```
data1
+----+-------+
| ID | BNR   | 
+----+-------+
|  1 | 123   | 
|  2 | 234   |
|  3 | NA    | 
|  4 | 456   | 
|  5 | 677   |
|  6 | NA    | 
+----+-------+

data2
+----+-------+
| ID | BNR   | 
+----+-------+
|  1 | 123   | 
|  2 | 234   |
|  3 | 345   | 
|  4 | 456   | 
|  5 | 677   |
|  6 | NA    | 
+----+-------+
dat
+----+-------+-------+-----------+
| ID | BNR.x | BNR.y |BNR.x_error|
+----+-------+-------+-----------+
|  1 | 123   | NA    |FALSE      |
|  2 | 234   | 234   |FALSE      |
|  3 | NA    | 345   |FALSE      |
|  4 | 456   | 456   |FALSE      |
|  5 | 677   | 677   |FALSE      |
|  6 | NA    | NA    |NA         |
+----+-------+-------+-----------+

desired output
+----+-------+
| ID | BNR   | 
+----+-------+
|  1 | 123   |
|  2 | 234   | 
|  3 | 345   | 
|  4 | 456   | 
|  5 | 677   | 
|  6 | NA    | 
+----+-------+
```

Comment: Could you please provide a sample data, and explain what you are trying to do ?

Comment: Could you also show us how you got to obtain `dat`. I say this because, there might be a way to get your result directly with `merge` or other alternatives. Of course, I'll try to find what's happening in your code. But just in case you're interested in alternatives.

Comment: Yes, better and faster code is of course always nicer, I'll add the full code. I've only been using R for 1 week so it's probably not great yet.

Comment: Sorry to ask for more things, but can you show us `data1`, `data2` and your `desired output`? That would allow us to provide straightforward results, which I guess you'd desire more (it'll be shorter).

Comment: Adding more info is never a problem if it lets you help me. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest replacing:

```
sub(".x_error",".x",colnames(dat[k]))]
```

with:

```
sub("\\.x_error", "\\.x", colnames(dat[k]))]
```

if you wish to replace an actual `.`. You have to escape `.` with `\\.`. A `.` in regex means `any character`.

Even better, since you are replacing `.` with `.` why not just say:

```
sub("x_error", "x", colnames(dat[k]))]
```

(or) if there is no other `_error` other than `x_error`, simply:

```
sub("_error", "", colnames(dat[k]))]
```

**Edit:** The problem seems to be that your data format seems to be loading additional columns on the left and the right. You can select the columns you want first and then merge.

```
d1 <- read.table(textConnection("| ID | BNR   | 
|  1 | 123   | 
|  2 | 234   |
|  3 | NA    | 
|  4 | 456   | 
|  5 | 677   |
|  6 | NA    |"), sep = "|", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)[,2:3]

d1$BNR <- as.numeric(d1$BNR)

d2 <- read.table(textConnection("|  1 | 123   | 
|  2 | 234   |
|  3 | 345   | 
|  4 | 456   | 
|  5 | 677   |
|  6 | NA    |"), header = FALSE, sep = "|", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)[,2:3]

names(d2) <- c("ID", "BNR")
d2$BNR <- as.numeric(d2$BNR)

# > d1
#   ID BNR
# 1  1 123
# 2  2 234
# 3  3  NA
# 4  4 456
# 5  5 677
# 6  6  NA

# > d2
#   ID BNR
# 1  1 123
# 2  2 234
# 3  3 345
# 4  4 456
# 5  5 677
# 6  6  NA

dat <- merge(d1, d2, by="ID", all=T)
> dat

#   ID BNR.x BNR.y
# 1  1   123   123
# 2  2   234   234
# 3  3    NA   345
# 4  4   456   456
# 5  5   677   677
# 6  6    NA    NA

# replace all NA values in x from y
dat$BNR.x <- ifelse(is.na(dat$BNR.x), dat$BNR.y, dat$BNR.x)

# now remove y
dat$BNR.y <- null
```

Comment: Your first `if` statement is never `TRUE` unless you check for `grepl("\\.x_error, ...)`.

Comment: I don't know how, but it actually is `TRUE`. Changing to `"\\.x_error,...)` from `".x_error,...)` did not change anything in the `if` or `sub` methods.

Comment: hmm okay, I think I made a mistake. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I just realised I might have gone overboard in giving random info for this question. What I want to know is, very simplified, why `colnames(dat[1]) = "newname"` won't change the name of column 1 to newname? A variable containing "newname" or using `colnames(dat["oldname"] = "newname"` doesn't work either.

Comment: it won't work. you should do `colnames(dat)[1] <- "newname"` or if you dint know the column number but the name, `colnames(dat)[colnames(dat) == "oldname"] <- "newname"`

Comment: Heh. And that has taken me well over 6 hours. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about that! I dint quite get what the problem was from your code.